# Firebase-tools is not uploading newly created functions to Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am working on an Angular project and I am writing Firebase functions that I would like to deploy to Firebase. As I write more functions for Firebase and try to deploy them to Firebase using `firebase deploy --only functions`, only existing functions get deployed. More specifically, I have 16 functions that I would like to deploy to Firebase but only the same 12 get deployed.

So far, I have done the following to try to fix the problem:

1. I made sure that I am on the latest firebase-tools (6.7.0)
2. I have tried specifying the newly written functions I would like to deploy using `firebase deploy --only functions:<NEW FUNCTION NAME HERE>`
3. Remove all export functions from the functions/src/index.ts file and upload a blank index.ts. Even when using a blank index.ts file, the same functions still get deployed to Firebase.
4. I know there can be up to a 30-second delay when uploading functions to Firebase, so I have even waited for an entire night before trying to upload new functions.
5. I have started from complete scratch using `firebase init` to recreate the whole functions directory and it still keeps uploading the same functions.
6. I upgraded from the free Firebase plan to the Spark plan.

The following code is the main index.ts file which is located in functions/src/index.ts.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { request } from 'https';

// Local Functions Imports
import * as Permissions from './permissions';
import * as Groups from './groups';
import * as Shifts from './shifts';
import * as Roles from './roles';
import * as Session from './sessions';
import * as Users from './users';
import * as Slack from './slack';
import * as ScheduleChanges from './schedule-changes';
import * as Email from './email';

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

/* -------- USER MANAGEMENT -------------- */
export const createUser = Users.createUser;
export const addUserToDefaultJoinGroups = Users.addUserToDefaultJoinGroups;
export const deleteUser = Users.deleteUser;

/* -------- SESSION MANAGEMENT -------------- */
export const addSessionID = Session.addSessionID;

/* -------- ROLE MANAGEMENT -------------- */
export const addRoleID = Roles.addRoleID;
export const removeAllShiftsAssociatedWithRole = Roles.removeAllShiftsAssociatedWithRole;

/* -------- SHIFT MANAGEMENT -------------- */
export const addShiftID = Shifts.addShiftID;
export const hourly_job = Shifts.hourly_job;
export const changeShiftStatsTest = Shifts.changeShiftStatsTest;

/* -------- GROUPS MANAGEMENT -------------- */
export const addGroupID = Groups.addGroupID;
export const addGroupIDNewTestFunction = Groups.addGroupIDNewTestFunction;

/* -------- PERMISSIONS MANAGEMENT -------------- */
export const addPermissionID = Permissions.addPermissionID;

/* -------- Emailing -------------- */
export const sendWelcomeEmailToNewUser = Email.sendWelcomeEmailToNewUser;
export const sendWelcomeEmailToNewUser2 = Email.sendWelcomeEmailToNewUser2;

/* -------- SLACK MESSAGING MANAGEMENT -------------- */
export const sendWelcomingMessage = Slack.sendWelcomingMessage;

/* -------- SCHEDULE CHANGES MANAGEMENT -------------- */
export const addScheduleChangeID = ScheduleChanges.addScheduleChangeID;
```

As seen in the code above, there are 16 functions that should be deployed to Firebase. However, only 12 get deployed. The following code snippet is from functions/src/groups/index.ts. In this file, the addGroupID is an existing function which continually gets deployed to Firebase. On the other hand, addGroupIDNewTestFunction is a new function that isn't getting deployed to Firebase even though they are in the same file and being referenced the same way.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

export const addGroupID = functions.firestore
.document("organizations/{organizationID}/groups/{groupID}")
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    console.log("Adding group id");
    await admin.firestore()
    .doc(`organizations/${context.params.organizationID}/groups/${context.params.groupID}`).update({
        'groupID': context.params.groupID
    })
})

export const addGroupIDNewTestFunction = functions.firestore
.document("organizations/{organizationID}/groups2/{groupID}")
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    console.log("Adding group id");
    await admin.firestore()
    .doc(`organizations/${context.params.organizationID}/groups/${context.params.groupID}`).update({
        'groupID': context.params.groupID
    })
})
```

As mentioned previously, I have specified 16 functions in the main index.ts file that should get deployed to Firebase functions. However, only the existing 12 functions are getting deployed. The following code snippet is the output firebase gives me when I run `firebase deploy --only functions` inside the Angular project.

```sh
firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'university-scheduling'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

no-unused-variable is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.

Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration:
    use-input-property-decorator
    use-output-property-decorator
    use-host-property-decorator
Try upgrading TSLint and/or ensuring that you have all necessary custom rules installed.
If TSLint was recently upgraded, you may have old rules configured which need to be cleaned up.


WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/email/index.ts:2:13 - 'admin' is declared but its value is never read.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/index.ts:2:1 - All imports on this line are unused.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/index.ts:3:13 - 'moment' is declared but its value is never read.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/index.ts:4:1 - All imports on this line are unused.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/slack/index.ts:2:13 - 'admin' is declared but its value is never read.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/slack/index.ts:6:7 - 'request' is declared but its value is never read.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/slack/index.ts:7:7 - 'options' is declared but its value is never read.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/users/index.ts:3:1 - All imports on this line are unused.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/users/index.ts:43:11 - 'groups' is declared but itsvalue is never read.
WARNING: /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions/src/users/index.ts:65:11 - 'uid' is declared but its value is never read.

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build /Users/brandon/Dropbox/Bearforce_Scheduling/bearforce-website/functions
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (106.24 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
⚠  appEngineLocation us-central1
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function createUser(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function deleteUser(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function addSessionID(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function addRoleID(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function removeAllShiftsAssociatedWithRole(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function addShiftID(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function hourly_job(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function changeShiftStatsTest(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function addGroupID(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function addPermissionID(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function sendWelcomingMessage(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function addScheduleChangeID(us-central1)...
✔  scheduler: all necessary APIs are enabled
✔  functions[addPermissionID(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[createUser(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[addShiftID(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[changeShiftStatsTest(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[sendWelcomingMessage(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[hourly_job(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[addSessionID(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[deleteUser(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[addGroupID(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[removeAllShiftsAssociatedWithRole(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[addScheduleChangeID(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
✔  functions[addRoleID(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.

✔  Deploy complete!

Please note that it can take up to 30 seconds for your updated functions to propagate.
```

Comment: If you're sure these functions should all be deploying, please file a bug report with Firebase with the steps to reproduce in a new project.  If you can't reproduce in a new project, you should work with Firebase support to figure out what went wrong.  You might want to send them the output of the log generated when running with the --debug flag.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for that recommendation! I just submitted a help ticket just as you suggested and will post their recommendation when they get back to me.

Comment: Are you using `mailgun-js`? How did you import the mailgun-js? and how do you assign the key and domain? how did you send the email? Did you install `@types/mailgun-js`. I'm facing this problem and I can not get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the directory which is compiled js files.

The default is `functions/lib/`.

If you import like `../../foo.ts` anywhere at `functions/src` or `functions/src/tests`, etc then the compiled js file is `functions/lib/{any}/foo.js`.

The deploy target files are `functions/lib/*.js` only. So, `functions/lib/{any}/foo.js` is ignored.

You should change directory or files structure.

If the reason is test files then you should meke `tsconfig.json` for deploy and exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give you guys an update on the solution to the problem I described above. In one of my index.ts files, I had the following require statement, var mailgun = require('mailgun-js'). Whenever I replaced this the require statement with import * as mailgun from 'mailgun-js', all the functions were deployed properly.

The most confusing part about this whole issue was that I only received success messages even when things weren't working properly. I do thank you guys for the speedy support and all of your suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and the solution was Editing functions/src/index.ts instead of functions/lib/index.js

In my case it's index.ts because of I selected that option when initialized the project with "firebase init", your case depends on it, can be index.js too, but always on /src and not in /lib.

I think that the /lib folder if for the compiled file.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying functions the compiler converts the src/*.ts files into "lib/src/*.js" files.
Somehow I had some files hanging around from previous deployments in the "lib/*js" space. Sure enough these files were getting deployed but the files containing the new function I had created were located in "lib/src/*js. No new changes were being passed up into cloud functions.

and so I went into package.json and changed

```
"main": "lib/index.js",
```

to read

"main": "lib/src/index.js",

And  to cleanup I deleted all .js files from "lib/

I was back in business.